# How did Fawkes find the Chamber of Secrets?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter, the-chamber-of-secrets

In the climax of *Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*, when Voldemort set the basilisk on Harry, Dumbledore's phoenix Fawkes suddenly arrived in the Chamber with the Sorting Hat, from where Harry pulled the Sword of Gryffindor and killed the basilisk.

The question is, as nobody knows where the Chamber was prior to Harry and Ginny opening it, how did Fawkes find out where to go to help Harry? Was it that the bird always knew where the chamber was? Or did Dumbledore send him to help Harry? If so, why did Dumbledore himself never come?

Comment: I think Fawkes simply followed the person who was most loyal to Dumbledore at the moment, but I don't know if canon explains this.

Comment: Also check out http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17088/how-did-fawkes-get-into-the-chamber-of-secrets and https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/3onjtz/harry_potter_how_did_fawkes_know_where_the/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Throughout the book, we see that phoenixes have various abilities. One of these appears to be the ability to Apparate (or something very similar). We see this when the ministry attempts to arrest Dumbledore.

We also know that Fawkes was "called" by the devotion that Harry showed to Dumbledore. So we can deduce that, rather than him flying from Dumbledore's office through the entrance of the bathroom, Fawkes apparated close to Harry not really knowing/caring where it was as long as it was close to the event calling him.